# Xamarin PCL Custom List View not updating View

Tags: xamarin

Ok I have used the Xamarin Guide for Custom List View (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/listview/)

General Information I scan QR codes and add Information from that into a custom Listview adding an item into a List

I then set as the Items of the ListView

```
if (ScannedObjectList.Items.Count() != ScannedObjectListItems.Count())
{
    ScannedObjectList.Items = ScannedObjectListItems;
}
```

which happens once and through debugging I found that the ListView correctly updates the Items in the internal List Object but does not update the View with that Item in UWP after the first Time an item is added.
(on Android I have to force this with BeginRefresh+EndRefresh because it does not update every time I add an item).
On UWP i currently have a workaround by setting ScannedObjectList.Items to null followed by re-setting it to the Item List.

```
if(await DependencyService.Get<IDependencyService>().ExecuteCode("UWP"))
{
    ScannedTicketList.Items = null;
    ScannedTicketList.Items = ScannedTicketListItems;
}
```

The DependencyService function is only because this produces problems on Android.

My Question now is there a "clean" way to do this or am i generally doing something wrong? Cause i can't believe that this hack could ever be the intended way

(Did not post more code because it's essentially the same as in the Xamarin Example)

Comment: does your List's source implement INotifyCollectionChanged?

Comment: hmm ok no i haven't, might give this a shot. Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ScannedTicketList.BeginRefresh ();
ScannedTicketList.Items = ScannedTicketListItems;
ScannedTicketList.EndRefresh ();
```

Comment: Makes no difference on UWP.
On Android this solves a problem i have with 1 item always being left out of the list but on UWP aside from ListObj->null->ListObj won't update it..but that's kindof a hackjob